# Writing my own custom function inside jQuery 'draggable( )' to display alert message

Tags: jquery, html, draggable

I want display an alert message when I start's dragging, for that I searched many posts, blog, Jquery documentation and different sites. But I haven't get any appropriate answer for that.

Out what I searched, I tried to by using

```
 $("#myDiv").draggable(function(){
     start: function( event, ui ) {
         console.log("krishna");
     }
 });
```

Can any one please suggest me some solution for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/bn4tc/)

```
 $( "#myDiv" ).draggable({
  start: function( event, ui ) {
      alert('drag it');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$( "#myDiv" ).draggable(
 {start: 
     function() {alert("hi");}
 });
```